# Tableau - hide x axis labels except for one that we want to be displayed

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to hide few sensitive details from x axis and keep only the one that has to be sent to the client. Is there a way to achieve this on Tableau ?

Assume i have a bar chart.. My x-Axis has labels, (A, B, C).. I now want to display only C-bar chart and hide labels A and B from the bar chart

Thanks
Sachi

Answer (score 3):

1) If you don't want to show the labels for A and B, you can create a calculated field like

```
[New Label] = IF [Old Label] = "C" THEN [Old Label] ELSE NULL END
```

Use this as the new label and you won't see the Labels for A and B.

2) If you don't want to show the Bars for A and B altogether then just filter them out

3) If you are sharing the file and the client has Tableau desktop, he can always unhide/modify the views to take a peek into the sensitive info. The only way in this case, is to remove the data for A & B from the data source and share the resultant views only for C

OR, of course, use Tableau server (can't verify; limited experience)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can leave off typing "ELSE NULL" if you want. That is the default.